Convergence of Step Functions Generated by Uniformly Distributed Random Points
I have encountered a surprisingly complicated problem to solve and I'm looking for some help. It could be difficult because I don't have a background in probability and so don't know the appropriate terms to search, or it is a genuinely difficult thing to prove.
Preamble: Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then, for $n\geq 1$ we consider evenly spaced points $0 \leq x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n \leq 1$ and a partition $\mathcal{P}_n$ of the interval $[0,1]$ into exactly $n$ disjoint intervals so that each $x_i$ belongs to exactly one of these partition intervals. Using these points and the partition we can construct a step function approximation of $f$, denoted $f_n$, by assigning $f_n(x) = f(x_k)$ for all $x$ in the $k$th partition interval. Then, a typical exercise one might encounter in real analysis is to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0$, which follows form the uniform continuity of $f$.
My Problem: Now, suppose that for $n\geq 1$ we have $u_1,\dots,u_n$ drawn independently form the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and we set the $x_1,\dots,x_n$ to be the corresponding order statistics. My question is: if we construct the step functions $f_n$ as above, can we still get uniform convergence to the original function $f$ with high probability?
What I have so Far: A previous question on here has provided that if the $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the order statistics of the i.i.d. points $u_1,\dots,u_n$ we have that
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |x_{k+1} - x_{k}| \leq \delta \bigg) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n $$
where $x_0 = 0$, $x_{n+1} = 1$, and for all $\delta \in [1/(n+1),1]$.
Of course, once one can argue that with high probability the points become close together, one can again use uniform continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$ to get the desired result. However, I'm unable to get anything asymptotic out of the above formula. I've run simulations with $\delta = 1/\sqrt{n}$, for example, and the above probability quickly converges to 1 as $n \to \infty$, but again, I can't prove it.
Question: It seemed to me that my problem would have been answered at some point in the mathematical literature, but I can't find any reference. Therefore, could someone either point me to a reference or help me out with a proof here? Thank you!

As $n\to\infty$: Do we choose all new $x_i$s for each incrementation of $n$; or do we just add one new $x$ to the previous $x_i$s for each incrementation of $n$?

I think it's better to choose $n$ points each time instead of just adding one. However, I'm open to whatever gets the job done here.

For any $k\ge 1$, as $0\le 1 - k\delta<1$  we have [1]:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^kn^k(1 - k\delta)^n}{k!}=0.$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n=1+\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n=1.$$

Therefore, using the above result, by the uniform continuity of $f$  (which is continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$), as $n\to \infty$ we have
$$\|f_n - f\|_\infty \xrightarrow{\color{blue}{p}} 0,$$
which also implies
$$\|f_n - f\|_\infty \xrightarrow{\color{blue}{L_1}} 0,$$
using the dominated convergence theorem as $\|f_n - f\|$ can be bounded by some constant over $[0,1]$.

For any $\delta>0$, we have
$$\sum_{n=\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor-1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\bigg(\|\Delta_n\|_\infty=\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |x_{k+1} - x_{k}| > \delta \bigg) = \sum_{n=\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor-1}^\infty \left (1-\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n \right)=\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k \sum_{n=\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor-1}^\infty {n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n<\infty,$$
because each of the inner summations is a converging series, for example, for $\delta=\frac 1 2$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\bigg(\|\Delta_n\|_\infty=\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |x_{k+1} - x_{k}| > \delta \bigg) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (1-\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor} (-1)^k{n+1\choose k}(1 - k\delta)^n \right)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1) (0.5)^n=3 <\infty.$$
Thus, using Borel-Cantelli lemma [2] $\|\Delta_n\|_\infty \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$. As  $f$ is also a Lipschitz continuous function on $[0,1]$, for some $C>0$ we have
$$0\le\|f_n - f\|_\infty \le C \|\Delta_n\|_\infty$$
Finally, by applying the squeeze theorem for almost sure convergence [3], as $n\to \infty$ we have
$$ \|f_n - f\|_\infty \xrightarrow{\color{blue}{\text{a.s.}}} 0.$$

Thanks Amir! One question: What does the sup-norm of f_n - f converging in L^1 mean?

@JasonBramburger You are welcome! It means
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left | |f_n - f|\infty-0 \right |1=\lim{n\to \infty} \mathbb E \left ( \left | |f_n - f|\infty-0 \right | \right ) =\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb E \left ( |f_n - f|_\infty \right )=0$$
where recall that $f_n$ is a function with a random structure depending on oder statistics $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
